# How is this app able to dim my laptop screen on Windows below 0 and how to replicate this through terminal commands?

Tags: windows-10, display, powershell, terminal, brightness

I wanted to be able to dim my laptop screen below 0 in Windows 10 but wasn't able to do it through the terminal.

I tried using this command in Powershell to lower the brightness to -1 instead of the current value which is 0:

```
powershell -Command "(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(3,-1)"
```

but I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "-1", for "WmiSetBrightness" to type "System.Byte": "Cannot convert value
"-1" to type "System.Byte". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.""
At line:1 char:1
+ (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

However there is an app on the Internet called dimmer which is able to dim the screen past 0 and I wonder how I could replicate this using a terminal command instead.

Here's the app: https://www.nelsonpires.com/software/dimmer

Comment: You may not be able to without additional software. As per https://www.androidpolice.com/2013/06/21/ever-wish-you-could-dim-your-screen-below-0-brightness-sometimes-theres-an-app-for-that/ these apps generally work by floating a semi-translarent black image over the screen  so you will likely need to find a way to do something similar.

Comment: Your first parameter is 3 and is a UInt32 so 0 to 4 Gig. The second parameter is a UInt8 and so has a range of 0 to 255. However it specifies percentage so valid range is 0 to 100.